# How to make URL in instagram post to forcefully open in chrome or safari using javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, instagram, getusermedia

We have a web application which has getusermedia for camera access.

When I click on the website url on instagram or facebook mobile app, it doesn't allow the camera. How can I make the url to open in chrome or other browser instead of instagram app?

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell and attempt to run a URL.

This works for me (save as whatever.hta and execute it) on my system. Clicking on the button opens Google in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>HTA Test</title>
  <hta:application applicationname="HTA Test" scroll="yes" singleinstance="yes">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openURL()
  {
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      shell.run("http://www.google.com");
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="openURL()" value="Open Google">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works if I run hta file on laptop. But doesn't open chrome when I click on open chrome on instagram app